# Validation While Loop Only Repeating Every Other Time

Tags: c++

I'm creating a program that is an arithmetic quiz. The program displays a menu and presents a quiz depending on the option that the user chooses (1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, etc.).

My while loops that validate if the user answered a problem correctly or incorrectly seems to be repeating every other time as opposed to every time. This ends up affecting the correct/incorrect counters for how many questions a user answers correctly/incorrectly, and I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening - what do I need to fix?

I am also having issues where the loop doesn't end even if the user enters -1 to stop.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

// function prototypes
void showMenu();
int add(int, int);

// main function
int main()
{
    int choice = 0, answer = 0;    // user input
    int num1, num2;    // numbers for problem

    int correct_sum;    // correct answer
    int correct = 0, incorrect = 0;    // counters

    do 
    {
        // display program purpose to user
        cout << "********* Welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz *******\n";
        cout << '\n';

        // call showMenu function
        showMenu();
        cin >> choice;    // user inputs menu choice
        cout << '\n';

        // switch statement for menu choice
        switch (choice)
        {
        // addition
        case 1:
            do {
                // randomize numbers
                srand(time(NULL));        // random seed
                num1 = rand() % 9 + 1;    // random num1
                num2 = rand() % 9 + 1;    // random num2

                // display problem to user
                cout << "How much is " << num1 << " plus " << num2 << "?\n";
                cout << "Enter your answer (-1 to return to the menu)\n";
                cin >> answer;
                cout << '\n';

                // correct sum formula & call addition() function
                correct_sum = add(num1, num2);

                // while user's answer is WRONG and not -1
                while (answer != correct_sum && answer != -1)
                {
                    // display incorrect message
                    cout << "No. Please try again.\n";
                    incorrect++;    // increment incorrect counter

                    // ask user for input again
                    cout << "Enter your answer (-1 to return to the menu)\n";
                    cin >> answer;
                    cout << '\n';
                }

                // while user's answer is RIGHT
                while (answer == correct_sum)
                {
                    // display correct message
                    cout << "Very Good!\n";
                    correct++;    // increment correct counter

                    // randomize numbers again for different problem
                    srand(time(NULL));        // random seed
                    num1 = rand() % 9 + 1;    // random num1
                    num2 = rand() % 9 + 1;    // random num2

                    // show more problems to user until -1 is entered
                    cout << "How much is " << num1 << " plus " << num2 << "?\n";
                    cout << "Enter your answer (-1 to return to the menu)\n";
                    cin >> answer;
                    cout << '\n';
                }

            } while (answer != -1);

            if (answer == -1)
            {
                // display addition results when answer == STOP
                cout << "********* RESULTS *******\n";
                cout << '\n';
                cout << "Addition problems solved: " << (correct + incorrect) << '\n';
                cout << "Number answered correctly: " << correct << '\n';
                cout << "Number answered incorrectly: " << incorrect << '\n';

            }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// showMenu function
void showMenu()
{
    // display menu options
    cout << "MENU:\n";
    cout << '\n';

    cout << "1. Enter 1 for Addition\n";
    cout << "2. Enter 2 for Subtraction\n";
    cout << "3. Enter 3 for Multiplication\n";
    cout << "4. Enter 4 for Division\n";
    cout << "5. Enter 5 for Modulus\n";
    cout << "6. Enter 6 to Exit\n";

    cout << '\n';
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// add function
int add(int num1, int num2)
{
    return (num1 + num2);
}
```

Comment: Don't call `srand` multiple times, call it only *once* at the start of your program. Each time you call `srand` you reset the seed. If `time(NULL)` gives you the time in seconds, and `srand` is called twice the same second, the seed would be reset to the same value causing the `rand` function to return the same sequence.

Comment: So -- should i put `srand` at the start of `int main()`? 
Also, do I need to reset `num1` and `num2` multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have yo use `while` loop inside `do..while` loop, `if` condition will work there, Try below code i have commented some part of code.

```
   #include<iostream>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <ctime>
   using namespace std;

   // function prototypes
    void showMenu();
    int add(int, int);

   // showMenu function
   void showMenu()
  {
// display menu options
cout << "MENU:\n";
cout << '\n';

cout << "1. Enter 1 for Addition\n";
cout << "2. Enter 2 for Subtraction\n";
cout << "3. Enter 3 for Multiplication\n";
cout << "4. Enter 4 for Division\n";
cout << "5. Enter 5 for Modulus\n";
cout << "6. Enter 6 to Exit\n";

cout << '\n';
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// add function
int add(int num1, int num2)
{
  return (num1 + num2);
}

// main function
int main()
{
int choice = 0, answer = 0;    // user input
int num1, num2;    // numbers for problem

int correct_sum;    // correct answer
int correct = 0, incorrect = 0;    // counters

do 
{
    // display program purpose to user
    cout << "********* Welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz *******\n";
    cout << '\n';

    // call showMenu function
    showMenu();
    cin >> choice;    // user inputs menu choice
    cout << '\n';

    // switch statement for menu choice
    switch (choice)
    {
    // addition
    case 1:
        do {
            // randomize numbers
           // srand(time(NULL));        // random seed
            num1 = rand() % 9 + 1;    // random num1
            num2 = rand() % 9 + 1;    // random num2

            // display problem to user
            cout << "How much is " << num1 << " plus " << num2 << "?\n";
            cout << "Enter your answer (-1 to return to the menu)\n";
            cin >> answer;
            cout << '\n';

            // correct sum formula & call addition() function
            correct_sum = add(num1, num2);

            // while user's answer is WRONG and not -1
            while(answer != correct_sum && answer != -1)
            {
                // display incorrect message
                cout << "No. Please try again.\n";
                incorrect++;    // increment incorrect counter

                // ask user for input again
                cout << "Enter your answer (-1 to return to the menu)\n";
                cin >> answer;
                correct_sum = add(num1, num2);
                cout << '\n';
            }

            // while user's answer is RIGHT
            if (answer == correct_sum)
            {
                // display correct message
                cout << "Very Good!\n";
                correct++;    // increment correct counter

                // randomize numbers again for different problem
               // srand(time(NULL));        // random seed
                num1 = rand() % 9 + 1;    // random num1
                num2 = rand() % 9 + 1;    // random num2

                // show more problems to user until -1 is entered
                //cout << "How much is " << num1 << " plus " << num2 << "?\n";
                //cout << "Enter your answer (-1 to return to the menu)\n";
                //cin >> answer;
                cout << '\n';
            }

        } while (answer != -1);

        if (answer == -1)
        {
            // display addition results when answer == STOP
            cout << "********* RESULTS *******\n";
            cout << '\n';
            cout << "Addition problems solved: " << (correct + incorrect) << '\n';
            cout << "Number answered correctly: " << correct << '\n';
            cout << "Number answered incorrectly: " << incorrect << '\n';

        }
    }

}while (answer != -1);

}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Output of above code now if answer is not correct

```
                ********* Welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz *******

                MENU:

                1. Enter 1 for Addition
                2. Enter 2 for Subtraction
                3. Enter 3 for Multiplication
                4. Enter 4 for Division
                5. Enter 5 for Modulus
                6. Enter 6 to Exit

                1

                How much is 6 plus 9?
                Enter your answer (-1 to return to the menu)
                10

                No. Please try again.
                Enter your answer (-1 to return to the menu)
                10

                No. Please try again.
                Enter your answer (-1 to return to the menu)
                10

                No. Please try again.
                Enter your answer (-1 to return to the menu)
                10

                No. Please try again.
                Enter your answer (-1 to return to the menu)
                10

                No. Please try again.
                Enter your answer (-1 to return to the menu)
                10

                No. Please try again.
                Enter your answer (-1 to return to the menu)
                10
```

I hope you are expecting this.

Comment: thank you, this fixed my issue with my loop for validating correct answers.  However, now I'm having an issue with the loop for validating incorrect answers -- it only shows `No. Please try again.` and asks for input again once, and after an incorrect answer is entered again, it generates a completely new problem.

Comment: If i get you correctly, i have updated code, Please try if this is working as per your expectations.

Comment: tried it - unfortunately, I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: The loop that validates if a user entered an incorrect answer repeats only once with `"No. Please try again."` even if the user enters an incorrect answer again -- after the user enters a second incorrect answer, the program generates and displays a completely new problem for the user to solve

Comment: I have updated code and paste output of the code, i hope you are expecting this, if so you can accept the answer :)